# Access Denied in Virtual Box

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2, virtual-machine

I am working on Linux / Ubuntu by using Virtual Box. I have 2 Virtual Machine Names, one is `Alice`, the other is `Bob`. `Bob` is my server.

I am trying to access files in `Alice` by typing `Bob`'s IP address. In `Bob` Machine I have `public_html` as a folder that has different php files.

In addition I have a login file inside `public_html`. I am able to access `info.php` & `session1.php`.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Here is my problem:
When I try to access `register.php` inside login it gives me Error 500

[image: img5]

I have tried many different ways to fix this error.

I hope there is a way to access `/login/register.php`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format images and inline code so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit the question and provide what you have tried and any additional details that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It show's ERROR 500 means your ASP syntax error, ACCESS database connection statement error, file reference and contains the path error, the server does not support the use of components such as FSO, etc. so you i only can give you some tips to check it as below.

Comment: Actually, I am able to access other php files in same directory but when I try to access this file inside a folder it gives me Error 500.

Comment: The  'session1.php' have used database connection ? if not ,maybe it's connect to DB failed.